# Express require a query parameter

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have a route `/ressource`. I can call this route with a query parameter `/ressource?param=ABC`which I can retrieve in Node with:

```
app.get('/ressource', function (req, res) {
    const parameter = req.query.param
})
```

Now, is there a predefined way I can require the parameter which throws an error for request to `/ressource` without `?param=ABC`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) to get the query parameter and use `next` callback function to throw an error like

```
app.get('/ressource', function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.query.param) {
        const err = new Error('Required query params missing');
        err.status = 400;
        next(err);
    }
    // continue
    const parameter = req.body.param
})
```

Comment: It's important to note that the condition `!req.query.param` will evaluate to true for all falsey values. i.e. if `req.query.param` is `false`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `""` (empty string), and `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In express, query is automatically parsed and put into the `req.query` object, not the `req.param` object.

So you can access it like this:

```
const parameter = req.query.parameter;
```

read [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) on expressjs docs.

Answer (score 0):

There are no predefined way to.
You can choose to check it yourself inside the callback function:

```
if (!req.query.parameter) {
     res.send('parameter is missing');
}
```

or to use a [router middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) which would serve the same purpose